# comand "lspci" does not show the the IVSHMEM device

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, libvirt, pci-e

I met a problem when I tried to use IVSHMEM.
Below is the configuration from my side:

1. vm xml configuration for IVSHMEM device:

```
<shmem name='ivshmem'>
    <model type='ivshmem-plain'/>
    <size unit='M'>2</size>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x10' function='0x0'/>
</shmem>
```

2. after the booting up and I found the qemu commandline ideedly have the device option:

   ps aux | grep ivshmem

> /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
> .......(ignore other options)
> -object memory-backend-file,id=shmmem-shmem0,mem-path=/dev/shm/hostmem,size=4194304,share=yes -device ivshmem-plain,id=shmem0,memdev=shmmem-shmem0,bus=pcie.0,addr=0x10

3. lspci command  not shown the device.
4. lshw command indeedly show the device:

```
*-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Inter-VM shared memory
             vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fcc1c000-fcc1c0ff memory:fdc00000-fdffffff
```

My host os and gust vm os is ubuntu 20.04 and version is:

```
uname -a
```

5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Anything input on this one?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to load the generic driver:

```
modprobe uio_pci_generic
```

Then you will see the PCI device.

Afterwards you can load your own kernel module by using

```
insmod uio_ivshmem.ko
```

Note that you probably need to build the module first.